# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000

Tags: node.js, express, kill, nodemon

so i have been working on a node backend project for a while now and suddnely i started encountering this error with my nodemon crashing everytime it tries to restart the app.
[image]

The common fix for this is just to change the port and restart the server, but the problem is each time you change the port and nodemon tries to restart the app, it crashes.
Another fix is to kill the process and resstart the app like so

```
lsof -i tcp:8000
sudo kill -9 PROCESS_ID
```

How ever this solution isnt long lasting as the app still crashes when nodemon tries to restart the app.

Does anyone have a better fix to this, i will really appreciayte, this errors are slowing down my development.

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo`, you have the rights to kill your own processes.

Comment: Did you get it? same problem here.